# SQL get rows matching ALL conditions

Tags: sql, having-clause

I would like to retrieve all rows matching a set of conditions on the same column. But I would like the rows only if ALL the conditions are good, and no row if only one condition fails.
For example, taking this table:

```
|id|name|
---------
|1 |toto|
|2 |tata|
```

I would like to be able to request if "tata" && "toto" are in this table. But when asking if "tata" and "tuto" are in, I would like an empty response if one of argument is in not in the table, for example asking if "toto" && "tutu" are included in the table.
How can I do that ?
Currently, I'am doing one query per argument, which is not very efficient. I tried several solutions including  a subselect or a group+having, but no one is working like I want.

thanks for your support !
cheers

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking.  Please give some sample output to go with your sample input, and include all of the queries that you've tried thus far.  Also, please indicate which RDBMS you're using.

Comment: Are you asking how to return rows every single one of your conditions is found in the table, spread over X rows?  So in you example, if the table didn't have toto, or tata, you wouldn't return any rows?

Comment: For me it is pretty clear, what is being asked. Important details are missing, though. 1) Is the column `name` unique? 2) Which RDBMS?

Comment: The relational operator you require is [division](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra#Division_.28.C3.B7.29), popularly known as ["the supplier who supplies all parts"](http://www.dbdebunk.com/page/page/772076.htm). [Exact division](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/) or with a remainder? How to handle an empty divisior? More detail are required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't the most efficient way, but this query would work.

```
SELECT * FROM table_name 
WHERE (name = 'toto' OR name = 'tata') 
AND ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_name WHERE name = 'toto') > 0 
AND ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_name WHERE name = 'tata') > 0
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a little vague. If the names are unique, you could count the matching rows that match a where clause:

```
where name='toto' or name='tata'
```

If the count is 2, then you know both matched. If name is not unique you could potentially select the first ID (select top 1 id ...) that matches each in a union and count those with an outer select.

Even if you had an arbitrary number of names to match, you could create a stored procedure or code in whatever top-level language you are using to build the select statement.

Comment: No this one doesn't work because if request for "toto" and "tuto" I would have at least one row in my response. I want all the requested matching rows or none.

Comment: I said to select count(*) with that where clause. To get two as a result back, you'd have to have one of each. This assumes the names are unique, as noted.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 1 AS found FROM hehe
WHERE 1 IN (SELECT 1 FROM hehe WHERE name='tata')
  AND 1 IN (SELECT 1 FROM hehe WHERE name='toto')
```

Answer (score 0):

If `name` is unique you can simplify to:

```
SELECT *
FROM   tbl
WHERE  name IN ('toto', 'tata')
AND    (SELECT count(*) FROM tbl WHERE name IN ('toto', 'tata')) > 1;
```

If it isn't:

```
SELECT *
FROM   tbl
WHERE  name IN ('toto', 'tata')
AND    EXISTS (SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE name = 'toto')
AND    EXISTS (SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE name = 'tata');
```

Or, in PostgreSQL, MySQL and possibly others:

```
SELECT *
FROM   tbl
WHERE  name IN ('toto', 'tata')
AND    (SELECT count(DISTINCT name) FROM tbl WHERE name IN ('toto', 'tata')) > 1;
```

Comment: These techniques require dynamic SQL if the divisor changes. Better IMO to use [one of the common division approaches](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/) using a divisor **table** i.e. data driven. Note the OP strongly suggests they are using a divisor **table**.